# How to use github action to follow another repo newest release?

Tags: docker, github-actions

I'm trying to use github action to build a docker image automatically. And this image is related to a package that must be installed by dpkg from another github repo release (the package in apt is too old). How could I use github action to follow some repo release?

I have build a none-follow version(just use apt), like:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:unstable-slim
RUN apt update -y && apt install git somepackage -y
```

**CI.yml**

```yaml
name: docker
run-name: auto build image

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      -
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          tags: leenhawk/hexo_env:latest
```

I think there should a hook that follow another repo and a getter to get release version.(The github release don't have latest package)

Comment: See [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch).

Comment: You would need to trigger this workflow when a release is generated on the other repository. To do so, as Azeem suggested above, you could use a `workflow_dispatch` event on this repository workflow, and send a `dispatch event` (using Github API or an action) from the workflow creating the release in the other repository.